# RediSearch - Get the JSON objects sorted in the same way after update of any field

Tags: redis, spring-data-redis, redis-search

I have created an index on RediSearch that includes multiple fields, for example `param1` and `param2`.

I perform the search using **FT.SEARCH** executing the following command.

```
FT.SEARCH "index" "@id:{4555bcbd\\-1d15\\-46f1\\-9acb\\-91e29c1f63f5} @param1:{ee2aa256\\-5c67\\-42cb\\-871f\\-a402fcdf2160}" "SORTBY" "param2"  DESC LIMIT 0 3000
```

The search produces a list of objects. When I update for example `param2` and execute the above command, the list changes. The latest updated object appears at the top of the list.

I tried to use multiple sorting fields but `FT.SEARCH` does not support sorting by multiple fields.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My custom solution included adding a `index` field for every object I store. Then, use `FT.AGGREGATE` function to query and sort by multiple fields `param2` and `index`. Because in constract to `FT.SEARCH`, `FT.AGGREGATE` supports multiple field sorting.

```
FT.AGGREGATE "index" "@idRicerca:{4555bcbd\\-1d15\\-46f1\\-9acb\\-91e29c1f63f5} @bankId:{ee2aa256\\-5c67\\-42cb\\-871f\\-a402fcdf2160}" 
LOAD "2" "@idRicerca" "@bankId" 
LIMIT "0" "3000" 
SORTBY "4" "@bankName" "DESC" "@index" "DESC"
```

Comment: Also, sorting by Id instead of index, can work perfectly fine.